# Google Spreadsheet combining rows into new sheet

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google forms to collect student information and gather it into a spreadsheet. The form will collect scores and feedback from two raters for a series of questions for each student. So, each student will have two rows per question (one for each rater's form data). It will look something like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvImhr5O8tEddG1hMDdlMXNkWnFLZTd3UE9OWjRMaVE&usp=sharing

I'd like to be able to combine the information into one row on a separate sheet (see sheet 2). I'm wondering if there is a function or script or add-on that will search to find the matching rows (Student, Question, Retake, Rater1/2) and copy that information into a new sheet, followed by the score and feedback information as well. I'd like all the data from both raters to be in one row (per student/question).

Is there a way to do that?

My ultimate goal is to use the Autocrat add-on to merge the information into a PDF and have it emailed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a few standard formulas.

First, in the *Combined* sheet, you can fill the **ID** and **Name** fields simply by referencing the *Contact* sheet, like this: `=Contact!B2` for **ID** and `=Contact!B3` for **Name**.

Next, for the **Question 1: Behavior** field, for example, you'll use a formula like this:

```
=INDEX(Scores!$A$2:$H$11,MATCH(1,(Scores!$C$2:$C$11=$B2)*(Scores!$D$2:$D$11=$E$1),0),4)
```

I'll do my best to break that down for you... from left to right:

- `Scores!$A$2:$H$11` references the all the values in the *Scores* sheet. You'll only have to change $H$11 if the size of that sheet changes, or you can just set it to a really big value from the get go.
- `Scores!$C$2:$C$11` references the **ID** field in the *Scores* sheet. Again, you'll only have to change $C$11 if the size of that sheet changes.
- `$B2` References the **ID** field on current row in the *Combined* sheet. The number should match whatever row you're on, but Sheets should change that for you automatically if you copy and paste the formula down a column.
- `Scores!$D$2:$D$11` references the **Question** field in the *Scores* sheet. Like before, you'll only have to change $D$11 if the size of that sheet changes.
- `$E$1` references the field name, "Question 1: Behavior", in the *Combined* sheet. You'll have to change this to $M$1 for all of the "Q2" fields.
- The 4 at the end of the formula determines which field from the *Scores* sheet is inserted in this cell. The **Question** field is the fourth from the left, hence 4. When you insert the **Retake** field, you change the number to 5, etc.

I hope this doesn't seem too tedious or convoluted because it's actually pretty straightforward. After you get the formula working for the first field, it'll take you less than ten minutes to do all the others.